# How to pass arguments to Bash Shell in Babun when integrated in Conemu?

Tags: bash, conemu, babun

I'm using [Babun](http://babun.github.io/) 1.2.0 with [Conemu](https://conemu.github.io/) 161206 [32] and I'm trying to run bash in interactive mode.

I'm using the following Conemu Task paramaters:

```
/icon "%BABUN%\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe" /dir "%userprofile%"
```

(The `%BABUN%` environment variable points to the directory containing `.babun`)

The command is:

```
%BABUN%\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash.exe --login -i
```

The `--login -i` is getting ignored.

**What I've tried:**

1. Placing `/bin/bash.exe` in quotes causes Conemu to crash. So this does not work: `%BABUN%\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 "/bin/bash.exe --login -i"`
2. Moving `--login -i` and placing it after `...\mintty.exe` also does not work.

**What is the correct way to pass arguments (`--login -i`) to bash?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering my own question with a solution for my problem. It does not answer my question about passing arguments to bash, but it does allow me to run the Bash shell in Babun's Cygwin in interactive mode with ConEmu.

In **ConEmu** go to `Settings --> Startup --> Tasks`. Select the predefined Babun task (or create one) and enter the following for...

**Task parameters**: `/icon "%BABUN%\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe" /dir "%userprofile%"`

**Commands**: `%BABUN%\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --login -i`

Instead of point the command to mintty.exe I'm pointing it to bash.exe directly.